# How to draw F letter with SVG path?

Tags: svg

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

This is my SVG code (M letter):

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
 <path d="M3 3 H17 V17 H3 V3 M5 5 V15 H7 V9 H9 V11 H11 V9 H13 V15 H15 V5 H13 V7 H11 V9 H9 V7 H7 V5 H5" fill="#333333" stroke="transparent" />
 </svg>
```

M: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByKAc.png ✓

F: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhtbO.png

How to draw the F letter with path?

Comment: At the top right is a link to change the language: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: Download an SVG editor such as Inkscape and use it to draw an F, or anything else you want.

Comment: try this `d="M3 3 H17 V17 H3 V3 ZM5 5 V15 H7 V11 H15 V9 H7 V7 H15 V5z"`